# WFP Usercontrol, trigger on Enter-key hit

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

(Using WPF application)

The situation:
Within a WPF application, i made a WPF usercontrol, that has been placed multiple times within the application window.

In the usercontroll is a button that does something. For example just does a simple messagebox.

What i want to do is activate the button when the Enter-key is pressed.

But here is the problem.
If i would make that within the usercontrol, will it press all the buttons of each usercontrol instance in the apllication ?

What is the right way of dealing with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will it press all the buttons of each usercontrol instance in the apllication ?

No. When you handle Enter key, only one instance would be involved, typically one that contains input focus.

For further reading, you can start [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing)

Comment: aaah yes! ofcourse! So logical because the fucus is somewhere in the application, not in a total overview way. I was thinking wrong.  thanks for the answer. helped a lot!